# Wrong columns when groupby in Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Have the following excel

[image]

I'm trying to get grouped data frame by every week with average `Value`. Code below:

```
df = pandas.read_excel("excel.xls", parse_dates=["Date"], dayfirst=False)
mean = df.groupby([df["Date"].dt.year, df["Date"].dt.week]).mean()
```

the result:

[image]

But i'd like to get the next one:

[image]

What I do wrong ??

Comment: how about renaming first : `mean = df.groupby([df["Date"].dt.year.rename('Year'), df["Date"].dt.week.rename('Week')]).mean()`

Comment: Rename the grouping series: `[df["Date"].dt.year.rename('Year'), df["Date"].dt.week.rename('Week')]`

Comment: @ALollz @anky_91 then i cannot do the thing like this `mean["Year"]`

Comment: @anky_91 not workig (KeyError: 'Year')

Comment: `mean.reset_index()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yeeeeeeeep. Thank you guys so much